# Class method not changing the class variable's value

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

Class method not changing the variable of a class variable

```
class Employee:

    raise_amount = 1.04


    def __init__(self,first,last,pay):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.pay = pay
        self.email = first+'.'+last+'@company.com'

    def fullname(self):
        return ('{} {}'.format(self.first,self.last))

    def apply_raise(self):
        self.pay = (self.pay * raise_amount)


employee_1=Employee('Bling','Blong',50000)
employee_2=Employee('Test','User',60000)


print (employee_1.pay)
employee_1.apply_raise
print (employee_1.pay)
```

After I apply the raise method on employee_1, the next line should print out the incremented salary. But it still shows the old salary of 50000.

Comment: You don't have parentheses at the end of `employee_1.apply_raise`.  You need parentheses to _call_ a function, otherwise you're just _referring_ to it.

Comment: `employee_1.apply_raise` doesn't call the method

Comment: When I use: employee_1.apply_raise(), I get an error of _NameError: global name 'raise_amount' is not defined_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code snippet,

```
 raise_amount = 1.04 
 def __init__(self,first,last,pay):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.pay = pay
        self.email = first+'.'+last+'@company.com'
```

Add `self.raise_amount = 1.04` to `__init__()` and remove `raise_amount = 1.04`

`self` keyword is used to refer to the class instance and without self it means that it is just a local variable. 
In this function,

```
    def apply_raise(self):
        self.pay = (self.pay * raise_amount)
```

Change the variable `raise_amount` to `self.raise_amount`

And lastly outside class, change `employee_1.apply_raise` to `employee_1.apply_raise()`

To call a method, use parentheses`()` at the end

Answer (score 1):

Here you made 2 mistakes in the code:
Mistake 1. Here in

```
 def apply_raise(self):

    self.pay = (self.pay * raise_amount)
```

it should be **self.raise_amount**

Mistake 2. In function call

```
print (employee_1.pay)

  employee_1.apply_raise

  print (employee_1.pay)
```

Here you should **add '()' at end of employee_1.apply_raise to make it employee_1.apply_raise()**

Initially the function apply_raise() was not being called, so no increment was made.

Comment: self.raisabount in your first comment will get a copy of the class level attribute.  It will work but the behavior is a bit off from what I think you think it is.